# how to listen to changes in network connectivity in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I've been searching for a long time for a way to listen to network changes not only when I close or open WiFi, but also to detect if I'm connected to WiFi but there is no internet in React. I tried using the package **https://github.com/cwise89/react-detect-offline**, but I noticed it sends a request to an API every 5 seconds. So, I'm searching for a more optimized solution , so i want to implement thee same behavior in facebook.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40248639/detect-network-connection-in-react-redux-app-if-offline-hide-component-from-u

Comment: No, it uses navigator.onLine, which is not fully browsers supported and not reliable.

Comment: It is supported on most browsers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/onLine#browser_compatibility if that does not work for you try this hook https://gist.githubusercontent.com/patrickcze/2814e93a7988654be4268232f80ff6a9/raw/62cbad7332b7e1f631b3b10a6959ed16bbacc1b4/useOnlineStatus.tsx

Comment: for me it not works , it always return true , i'm using the latest version from chrome that is 122.0.6261.129 , even window.addEventListener("online",()=>{}) seems not working anymore in chrome , even it works it will listen for connection if i'm connected or not , but will not listen if i'm connected but the internet is down

Comment: I doubt you will find a stable API for this. Many browsers were known to develop bugs on this over the years. Even good ABIs I know didn’t work well for many years.

Comment: To check the internet connectivity in real time, you will have to send a request to somewhere (e.g. to google.com) periodically. `react-detect-offline` library doesn't seem bad as every 5 sec sounds reasonable. You can also modify the time interval (to 10 sec or whatever) with that library. I also have a native solution without using any package, but it still uses `navigator.onLine` and time interval requests. It basically works as same as `react-detect-offline` library, and works on most of browsers.